# sharepoint new form get Domain\Username from people picker

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a PeoplePicker field in my Newform.aspx where I want to pick Domain\Username of that particular field and update in another field.

I think there is some issue while using as below:

```
strUser = properties.AfterProperties["PeoplePicker"].ToString();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

SPUser spUser = web.EnsureUser(strUser);
spUser = spUser.LoginName; \\This returns Domain\Username

if (properties.AfterProperties["PeoplePicker"] != null)
{
  properties.AfterProperties["AnotherField"] = spUser;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? spUser prolly is typeof string, AnotherField property, too? Any debug informations?

Comment: @YvesR it is updating fine in AnotherField when i get the info from a single line of text, but not from peoplePicker..i think i have to convert to some other format after i get the data from peoplePicker

Answer (score 1):

yes,
i think there is issue.

when we use

```
properties.AfterProperties["PeoplePicker"].ToString();
```

then it returns -1 as a user id.

So the solution may be.
We must first extract the account name from the above value.
Then need to retrive user from that account name.
Then we can set it to other property value.